# Custom keymapping for games?

Tags: bluetooth, game-controllers

I'm using an iPega Bluetooth controller with my HTC Desire 510. For most things it works great, but I am running into some issues with Ravensword 2. Ravensword finds my controller and connects fine, but when I start playing, certain actions can't be performed (attacking being one of them).

Is there a way to custom map my controller? I'm not on a rooted phone as I can't find a reliable way to root this device.

Answer (score 0):

For mapping controllers [Mantis Gamepad Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.mantispro.gamepad&hl=en&gl=US),
[Odo Gamepad Mapper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.swampsoft.odogamepadmapper&hl=en&gl=US&pli=1), and [Octopus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.swampsoft.odogamepadmapper&hl=en&gl=US&pli=1) is one of my favorite apps since i started playing with controllers. Buy the pro version if you dont want ads

*i'm currently using Mantis for mapping my xbox and playstation controller, i don't have wireless ones so i can't confirm if this will work or not.*